# Why I have a problem with the connection? c# winsock error System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Excepción de HRESULT: 0x800A9C54'

Tags: c#, winsock

I'm making two projects: "server" and "client". I want to make a chat room using winsock and C# but the following exception is thrown when I click the button "btnconnect" in "client":

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Excepción de HRESULT: 0x800A9C54'

Here is the code:

```
namespace Client1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int p = 850;
            Clientws.Connect(txtip.Text, p); // Exception occurs here
        }

        // Other methods...
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Clientws.Connect(txtip.Text, p);`? Please share the code for that too.

Comment: Do avoid using the ancient winsock ActiveX control, you'll have a hard time getting help at SO to diagnose these obscure exceptions.  Error code 40020 means "invalid operation on the current state".  One way to get it, I'd imagine, is to click the button when it is already connected.  Set the button's Enabled property to *false* after you connected.